# How to apply ORDER BY for more than two column in mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Below query,I try to sort(ascending) the result by reviewer name, movie title and then by review stars.

The query I written sort only the reviewer name and movie title only not all the three.

```
mysql> SELECT r.reviewername,m.movietitle,ra.reviewstars
-> FROM movie m JOIN rating ra,reviewers r
-> WHERE m.movieid=ra.movieid and
-> ra.reviewerid=r.reviewerid
-> ORDER BY
-> reviewername,
-> movietitle,
-> reviewstars;

+--------------+------------+-------------+
| reviewername | movietitle | reviewstars |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
| kevin        | annie hall |           4 |
| kevin        | bagubali   |           4 |
| nagaraj      | jumanji    |           2 |
| snagan       | vallavan   |           5 |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The data are actually sorted according to the ORDER BY clause. What should have been the result? When the first attribute has the same value, the second is used. When the first two attributes have the same value, the third is used. But in your example the last case does not happen.

Comment: How to resolve this friend?

Comment: There is nothing to resolve. It works correctly. If you expected some other results, please tell us what that result is.

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name_1,column_name_2,column_name_3 ASC
```